# Google oauth - Getting roles assigned to a user using access_token

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-platform, roles, google-oauth

Is it possible to get the roles assigned to a user from the access token or id token that was generated by Google OAUTH server?

Comment: How are you defining Google roles?  Id token is a jwt dump here it https://jwt.io and you can see what it contains

Comment: I tried that but the it doesn't contain the roles assigned information

Comment: I have created custom roles on Google Cloud Platform console

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do that:

- First of all, you will use the access token corresponding to the account. Call the [tokeninfo endpoint](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth#calling-the-tokeninfo-endpoint) using the access token to retrieve email of the account (from the JSON response body). The URL that returns the email will be:

```js
url = "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?fields=email&access_token=" + access_token;
```

- The next step is retrieving chosen project members' IAM roles and checking whether the email from the previous step is among them (and if yes, with which role):

Get the existing IAM policy by calling [`getIamPolicy()`](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/reference/rest/v1/projects/getIamPolicy) with a HTTP request (replace `PROJECT-ID` with the project of your interest :

```
POST https://cloudresourcemanager.googleapis.com/v1/projects/PROJECT-ID:getIamPolicy
```

The responce body contains member emails and their roles.